# Which is best way and difference between service php5-fpm restart and reload?

Tags: php, nginx, github, amazon-ec2

When I pull my php code to multiple Amazon ec2 instance at a same time and want that modified code to run on servers so which is the best way to do without affecting users to get 5XX errors:

```
service php5-fpm restart 
and 
service php-fpm reload
```

And what is the difference between them? I'd appreciate a detailed explanation.

Comment: Multiple ec2 instances? I think your main issue more than anything else is  that your architecture is wrong sounds like you're running fpm on each server individually if you're running multiple instances you may as well run a/or many "processing" instance(s) instead for fpm and just use one or 2 of them for nginx with load balance proxy between them. That way you can round robin restart fpm on the instances and nobody will see 500 errors as nginx will sync to next available fpm instance if the first it hits is being restarted.

Answer (score 2):

Restart stops the service and starts it again (with new configuration changes).
However reload doesn't stop the service but merely re-reads its configuration file.

Be warned though, not all services behave as expected which makes restarting the service a safer/assured option.

For 500 errors, you might not want to restart the service on all servers at the same time.

Comment: The primary difference is that the master process isn't restarted, which means that any configuration changes affecting the master will not happen, such as new listen sockets.